# prevent suspend while streaming over samba

Tags: samba, suspend

Seems this is an open problem -- streaming over Samba apparently doesn't pause the idle timer on Ubuntu (12.10 Unity), so the machine will suspend after the usual 30 minutes despite the fact that I'm streaming something.

I found this solution for Gnome, but nothing for Unity: http://aikar.co/2011/03/03/ubuntu-prevent-sleep-samba/

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, Caffeine works if you tell it to active when smbd is running, but smbd doesn't stop or start based on when you're streaming -- it'll make the machine effectively never sleep and the display never turns off.

Comment: For a workaround so far I've just been VNCing into the machine and turning on caffeine whenever I start streaming media over samba. Not too clean, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

from the [linked thread](http://aikar.co/2011/03/03/ubuntu-prevent-sleep-samba/): this works fine in unity as an `*/30 * * * *` cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `/usr/bin/smbstatus | grep DENY | wc -l` == "0" ] ; then
    pm-suspend
else echo “Got user on SMB”
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576525/can-i-prevent-ubuntu-being-suspended-while-a-download-is-in-progress) question. You can use this [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576525/can-i-prevent-ubuntu-being-suspended-while-a-download-is-in-progress/661085#661085) provided there to prevent Ubuntu from suspend while any upload or download in progress. Change wlan0 to eth0 or use both if its applies.